# How can I randomly access text from bzip2 files?

Tags: compression, random-access, bzip2

I've been using [James Taylor's bzip-seek2](https://bitbucket.org/james_taylor/seek-bzip2/src/seek-bzip2/) script for randomly accessing the content of `.bz2` files. Wikipedia dumps all the articles in a single `XML` file which is compressed using `bzip2`.
I was trying to create a memory map for all Wikipedia articles compressed in `bzip` format but I was getting "data error".

There is no documentation present for this. Is there any way to create the memory map for this file?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "memory map for all Wikipedia articles?". What does that have to do with the title of this question? | Given that BZip2 is a single-file compressor (not an archiver) how are the individual articles represented in the stream and how do you tell them apart? There's just too little context provided here.

Comment: All the Wikipedia articles (current revision) are clubbed together in a single XML file.  This file is compressed using the bzip2 compression method. All I know is that it compresses block-wise and hence you can randomly access a block. I was able to do it for previous dumps using [James Taylor's bzip-seek2](https://bitbucket.org/james_taylor/seek-bzip2/src/seek-bzip2/). But it's not working on the current Wikipedia dump.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the latest version of `latest-all.json.bz2` although seek-bzip2's bzip-table program worked fine on the 26 Sep 2017 version of that file. Workaround: I bunzip'd the file and then used squashfs to compress it into a seekable format.